# Check whether excel row is present with the option of expand or collapse

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

While Looping through the rows in an Excel file in VBA, is it possible to determine if the row are grouped with expand and collapse option?

Using the image below as an example, if the script loops the below excel sheet as the input, I need to be able to determine if rows 7,9,13 and 21 are grouped (having the expand and collapse option).

Any idea on how to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: I has posted an answer which determines the outline level of a specific row. This can give indication of if the row is part of a group. What do you need to do with the data your loop provides (do you need to collapse groups or what?)

Comment: Am maintaining my task level details in excel. Main task is having expandable option and inside that all the sub tasks are there. Also there are cases where grouping is nested. So to read only sub tasks, i need to check whether the row can be expanded / collapsed. If yes then ignore. If no then it will be the sub task, so consider them.

Comment: OK, so has your original question been answered? U

Comment: No. In the code it says whether it is there in the group or not. It does not give me whether that is expandable/collapseable. Because when am running the loop, i need to ignore row 7,9,13,21.

Comment: Just update your question to include that you want to skip those rows. will be much easier to check the A Column for the Total Text, I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you can use is:

```
'r would be the row position
Rows(r).OutlineLevel
```

If it will return a value for the row outline level as seen in the 1 2 3 Column on the left of your image.

**EDIT**

Including the requirement from the OP in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34012705/check-whether-excel-row-is-present-with-the-option-of-expand-or-collapse?noredirect=1#comment55791469_34012705) that the line which have the Totals need to be ignored, the following script can be included:

```
'r being the row and 1 refering to Column 1 which is Column A
SearchString = Cells(r, 1)

If InStr(1, SearchString, "Total") > 0 Then

  'Insert Script here to do what you need to do to skip the row

Else

  'Insert script here to execute on the rows which are not totals


End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Each row has `.outlineLevel` property, which tells you level of grouping applied on it. In my example you can see sub which loop specified number of rows and print number of grouping applied on each row in selected range. 
Row without grouping have `outlineLevel` 1

```
    Sub isGrouped()
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set targetSheet = Sheets("nameYourSheet")

    Dim rowCounter As Long

    With targetSheet
        For rowCounter = 1 To 50
            Debug.Print .Rows(rowCounter).OutlineLevel

        Next rowCounter
    End With

End Sub
```